# Using item field to fill a transaction field in netsuite

Tags: netsuite

I have a currency field in transaction named "custbody_custom_cost";

I have a currency field in Item named "custitem_custom_cost"

I have a option field in Item named "Type", it can be an equipment or an acessory;

When an item is added to the Transaction, **If it is an equipment**, the transaction "Custom Cost" field need to be populated with the same value of this Item but it need to be done automatically.

I created a Saved Search that returns the Custom Cost of a Item if it is an equipment, now I'm trying to create a workflow that populates the transaction field. But when I create an action "define fields value", I don't know what to put on the formula.